# Understanding Vishnusuktam

Tags: vedas, vishnu, rig-veda, sanskrit, vedic

> **तद्विष्णोः परमं पदं सदा पश्यन्ति सूरयः । दिवीव चक्षुराततं । ।१.२२.२०.।
>
> तद्विप्रासो विपन्यवो जागृवांसः समिन्धते । विष्णोर्यत् परमं पदं ।।१.२२.२१.।** 
>  अत्र रावणभाष्यं । विष्णोर्व्यापनशीलस्याऽपि परमात्मनः तत् परमं परमार्थिकम् पदं अभिव्यक्तिस्थानम् । दिवि मूर्ध्नि भ्रूमध्ये वर्तते । त्रिपादस्यामृतम् दिवीतिश्रुतेः । सत्यज्ञानानन्दात्मकम् विष्णोः पदं । तत् किं ? यत् सूरयो महानुभावाञ्चक्षुराततं विस्तृतमिव कृत्वा सदा अव्यवधानेन पश्यन्ति निरन्तरं साक्षात् कुर्वन्ति । यद्वा चक्षुरर्थप्रकाशकम् । इव एवकारार्थे । .... [Ravana Bhashya of Rig Veda ed F.E. Hall, published in Journal of Asiatic Society of Bengal vol 31, 1862](https://archive.org/details/ravana_bhashya_of_rig_veda/Ravana%20Bhashya%20of%20Rig%20Veda%20-%20FE%20Hall%201862%20%28JASB%2031%29/)

I tried to read the Bhashya of this very first hymn and it looks like it is more of a lexical work than the meaning itself - the Bhashyakar is explaining the meaning of each and every word in detail. As far as I could translate it with all available references:
**विष्णोः** Even of the all-pervasive highest self,
**तत्** That highest one, the transcendental space-of-manifestation
**दिवि**    In between the eyebrows on the forehead; the eternal essence of the triad
**विष्णोः पदं** Source of truth, knowledge and bliss
**सूरयो**   The enlightened ones
**चक्षुराततं**  Expanded
**तत्** That which is expanded to the enlightened ones and they  always see it without interruption and constantly realize, or that which sheds light on the understanding of vision.
**इव**  Meaning expressed by “only/ Alone”
**आततं**    Just as it appears limited, so do they perceive
**तत्** Therefore.
**विप्रासो**    Scholars of the best opinion.
**विपन्यवो**    Intelligent(s)
**जागृवांसः**   Awakened, from a long dream, from the visible world.
**समिन्धते**    Looking at prosperity.                                                     In the state of practice, they look at the desire reached between the eyebrows through the spinal cavity. In the behavioural state, however, it means that they see the same as the perception of the whole object.

So, is it something about something that happens between the states of dreaming and waking up, or something related to the connexion between our nervous system and our so called "self"? What exactly do these *enligtened ones* see? What is this "space-of-manifestation", is it like some extra-cosmic void where everything is created, or is it our mind where imaginations and thoughts are formed out of nothing? Is this *all pervading* self some sort of field?  What does this *triad* refer to? I want to unjumble the above descriptions to something meaningful. Please give proper references.